# Input/output error while trying to mkdir in VM at the mounted location of GCS bucket

Tags: mount, gcsfuse

I m using gcsfuse in my VM in order to mount with google cloud storage bucket. while running the command "mkdir" as a root user in the mounted location, i am getting the error as below.

`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘243’: Input/output error`

Whereas, i am able to create the folder if i navigate to GCP console and create a folder structure inside storage bucket.
Not sure where is the issue now.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you run gcsfuse with flag --debug_fuse and --debug_gcs and share the logs.
See if this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382704/gcsfuse-input-output-error